# iPad OS - limiting user access to Find My app

Tags: ipad, ipados, find-my

After upgrading iOS to iPad OS 13.2.2 the new application appeared: Find My.

I have multiple devices linked to this apple account, but I want to block access to Find My on the particular iPad, so the user (for example child) can't see the rest of the devices.

The device should be visible from the Find My on another device.
In Find My iPhone I used to just log out from the app, here I can't see this option.

I was thinking about using "screen time" limits, but I cannot find a suitable option.