# Managing Find My on Child Tablets

Tags: ios, ipad

I am looking for out-of-the-box ways to control the Find My app on my children's iPads; whether that's external apps or otherwise. Apple support has not been helpful, and the only "mechanism" is to restrict the app to 1 minute per day.

As a parent, I need to see my kid's devices and locations. The issue here is that the kids will have access to mark parental devices as lost or play sounds. I see this as a security issue and sadly, yet another limitation of iOS with the all-or-nothing approach.

In the meantime, please [submit feedback to Apple](https://www.apple.com/feedback/) if you are also facing this issue.

Reference

- [How to prevent child from using Find My to interact with parent's device?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/388259/257929)
- [iPad OS - limiting user access to Find My app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/375052/257929)
- [Hide family member's devices on FindMy?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253409620)
- [Hiding devices in family sharing](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251379456)

Comment: Have you tried removing the app? You didn't used to be able to do it, but it looks like you can now. idk whether it would affect functionality & I can't test it [not willing to & don't have kids;)

Comment: @Tetsujin it can only be removed from the Home Screen